# Syntactic proof of existence of the Skolem normal form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The theorem states that for every closed formula $\tau$ of signature $\sigma$ there exists a formula $\tau'$ in the $\sum_2$ class (of the signature $\sigma$ with some additional predicate symbols) that is a validity iff $\tau$ is a validity.

The semantic proof that I know considers the dual question of satisfiability (since $\lnot \tau$ is satisfiable iff $\tau$ is not a validity) and thus instead proves that there exists a corresponding formula in $\prod_2$. It's probably easier shown by example: if the source formula is $\forall x \forall y \exists z \forall u \exists v \varphi(x, y, z, u, v)$, then the corresponding formula $\psi$ would be

\begin{align*}
\forall x \forall y \exists z &\ F(x, y, z) \land \\
\forall x \forall y \forall u \exists v &\ G(x, y, u, v) \land \\
\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall u \forall v &\ (F(x, y, z) \land G(x, y, u, v) \rightarrow \varphi (x, y, z, u, v)),
\end{align*}

which is a conjunction of $\prod_2$ formulas and thus is in $\prod_2$, and its negation is in $\sum_2$, as expected.

Clearly, it's satisfiable iff the original formula is satisfiable (as we're free to choose $F$ and $G$ to be the predicates corresponding to the Skolem functions), so we're done.

But can we prove the theorem purely syntactically, by considering derivations instead of the semantic notion of satisfiability? That is, in this case, can we show that $\{ \forall x \forall y \exists z \forall u \exists v \varphi(x, y, z, u, v) \} \vdash \psi$, and, in the other direction, $\{ \psi \} \vdash \forall x \forall y \exists z \forall u \exists v \varphi(x, y, z, u, v)$? Would that be insightful compared to the semantic proof? I tried to do the derivation myself, but got lost quickly, as I don't have much intuition for FOL derivations.

Comment: It's not true that a sentence and its Skolem form are deducible from each other; they are not logical consequences of each other.  The connection is only that one is satisfiable iff the other is satisfiable. (And for the duals, usually called the Herbrand form, one  is logically valid iff the other is logically valid.) I think Shoenfield's book "Mathematical Logic" has a syntactic proof of the Herbrand version, but I don't have my copy of the book handy so I can't check.

Comment: What I meant is if $\varphi$ is a validity and $\psi$ is its normal form, then if we manage to derive $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$, then $\psi$ is a validity too. But, reading your comment carefully, maybe this argument is indeed too strong, as I'd have to prove that $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ for every $\varphi$ while I only need to consider the case when $\varphi$ is a validity. On the other hand, I'm not sure how to syntactically derive (as the exercise suggests) the validity of $\psi$ otherwise except maybe by an inductive proof on the structure of $\varphi$, but that seems clumsy.

Comment: As for the duals, I likely meant something else - $\varphi$ is satisfiable if $\lnot \varphi$ is not a validity, but if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equisatisfiable then $\lnot \varphi$ and $\lnot \psi$ are equivalidities, so the connection between a formula and its Skolem form can be kind of extended to validities, can't it?

Comment: If by "kind of extended" you mean by negating the formulas, then yes; if you meant something else, then almost certainly no. In particular, it is not generally the case that a sentence is valid iff its Skolem form is valid.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong at the terminology (as my book never explicitly defines what's an SNF), or just the following argument is invalid. So, let $\varphi$ be some arbitrary validity, or equivalently $\lnot \varphi$ is not satisfiable, or equivalently $\text{SNF'}(\lnot \varphi) = \lnot \text{SNF}(\varphi)$ is not satisfiable (where SNF' is the negation of the SNF and is in class $\prod_2$, see my question for the example, and looks like it's possible to lift $\lnot$ out of it to get the SNF of the original formula), or equivalently $\text{SNF}(\varphi)$ is also a validity. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: SNF$(\neg\phi)$ is not the same as (nor equivalent to) $\neg\,$SNF$(\phi)$.

Comment: Yep, that's why it's $\text{SNF'}$ here, with extra `'` :) Or, in other words, one of them is in $\prod_2$, while the other is in $\sum_2$ (as expected with negations).